# invariant violation element type is invalid expected a string react native

Tags: react-native, expo

So this is my first application inside react-native and I'm running into the following error.

I've tried working on this bug for the past few days but haven't had much luck.

Below is a copy of my MainNavigator.js:

```
import DlLoading_2 from "./src/screens/DlLoading_2";
import DlMain from "./src/screens/DlMain";
import { createStackNavigator, createAppContainer } from "react- 
navigation";

const MainNavigator = createStackNavigator({
    DlLoading_2: {
      screen: DlLoading_2
    },
    DlMain: {
      screen: DlMain
    }
  },
  {
    headerMode: "none"
  }
  );

  export default createAppContainer(MainNavigator);
    render() ;
      return (
      < MainNavigator />
    ) ;
```

And here is a copy of my opening page:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Center } from "@builderx/utils";
import { View, StyleSheet, Image, Text } from "react-native";
import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import { MainNavigation } from '../screens/MainNavigator';
import { TouchableHighlight } from 'react-native'
import { AppContainer } from "../screens/MainNavigator"

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(MainNavigation);

export default class DlLoading_2 extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <AppContainer/>
      <View style={styles.root}>
        <Center />
          <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => 
this.navigation.navigate('DlMain')}/>
            <Image style={styles.blueDisk} source= . 
  {require('../assets/ComponentTMP_0-image.jpg')}/>
          <TouchableHighlight/>
        <Center horizontal> 
          <Image
                source={require("../assets/ComponentTMP_0- 
   image2.png")}
            style={styles.dlLogo}
          />
        </Center> 
        <Center horizontal>
        <Text style={styles.text}>TRANSINDENTAL 
MEDITATION</Text>
        </Center>
        <AppContainer/>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

Any help on this error would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few things going wrong in this. Let's take a look each file in turn

## MainNavigation.js

You've set up your MainNavigator correctly however you don't set up the AppContainer that way.

This is how I would set up your `MainNavigation.js`

```
import Screen1 from './Screen1';
import Screen2 from './Screen2';
import { createStackNavigator, createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';

const screens = {
  Screen1: {
    screen: Screen1
  },
  Screen2: {
    screen: Screen2
  }
}

const config = {
  headerMode: 'none',
  initialRouteName: 'Screen1'
}

const MainNavigator = createStackNavigator(screens, config);
export default createAppContainer(MainNavigator);
```

I prefer to separate everything out so that it is easy to see what everything is. The `createAppContainer` just wraps the `MainNavigator` you don't need to set a render function like you have done, as it is not being used and may lead to code errors.

In the options for the MainNavigator you can set your `initalRouteName` this is where the app will open on. If you want to open it on `Screen2` set it accordingly, if you don't set it it will default to the first one in the list.

## App.js

You have put in your `AppContainer` but then you have this `<View>` underneath it that is comprised of many things, including another `AppContainer`, where many of the tags are not closed properly.

I think that what is in the `View` should be on another screen in your MainNavigator, with that screen set as your `initialRouteName`.

This is how I would setup the `App.js`, you don't really need much more here.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import AppContainer from './MainNavigation';
export default class App extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
    }
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <AppContainer />
    )
  }
}
```

Here is a snack that allows you to navigate from Screen1 to Screen2 and back

https://snack.expo.io/r1FqD8VX4

## Closing tags

When you open tags for a component, like `View` they are opened like this

```
<View>
```

When you close the tags for that `View` they are closed like this

```
</View>
```

Anything that is contained between those tags are called that component's children, and are accessed inside that component by `this.props.children`.

Not all components need to take children, like the `Button` component. It is opened and closed with the one tag like so

```
<Button onPress={} title={'title'} />
```

If you are looking at using `TouchableHighlight` this is how you would write the code so that it wraps your Image correctly

```
<TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('DlMain')}>
    <Image style={styles.blueDisk} source={require('../assets/ComponentTMP_0-image.jpg')}/>
</TouchableHighlight>
```

Comment: You're absolute star, thank you so much man!! the help is massively appreciated! I've made the changes and so far everything looks good! The original error isn't there anymore, however the closing tag for <TouchableHighlight> is demanding a corresponding closing tag for view even though it's already been set.

Comment: Just realised there was a typo in my `TouchableHighlight` example. I have fixed it.

Comment: Can you create a snack showing where the issue is?

Comment: Hi Andrew, sorry for the slow reply! I've fixed the error inside the code now, however the new issue is just the touchable highlight not displaying the image.

Comment: Of course man, and again, thank you so much! you have no idea how much you've helped me out :)

Comment: I am really pleased that it worked for you :) Keep trying you will get there. It can be difficult but we all started at the beginning at one one time